# Linq to Entites Query does not retrieve the records

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

Since I need a query from 4 different entity sets (Medical, City, Region, MedicalServices), I have created a viewmodel as follows;

```
  public class MedicalCityRegionView
{
    public Entity.Medical V_Medical { get; set; }
    public Entity.City V_City {get;set;}
    public Entity.Region V_Region{get;set;}
    public Entity.MedicalService V_MedicalService{ get; set; }
}
```

And a class which gets the all records from those 4 tables as follows;

```
 public class EntityHandler
{
    public IQueryable<MedicalCityRegionView> GetAll(Entity.MedicalEntities MCR_View)
    {
        IQueryable<MedicalCityRegionView> result = from mID in MCR_View.Medicals
                     join cs in MCR_View.Cities on mID.CityFK equals cs.CityID
                     join reg in MCR_View.Regions on cs.RegionFK equals reg.RegionID

                     select new MedicalCityRegionView();

        return result;
    }
}
```

And this part is on the code behind;

```
 result = from mID in em.Medicals
          join ms in em.MedicalServices on mID.MsMedicalFK 
          equals ms.ServiceID
          join c in em.Cities on mID.CityFK equals c.CityID
          join reg in em.Regions on c.RegionFK equals 
          reg.RegionID

          where ms.ServiceID == SelectedMedicalService 
          &&
          c.CityID == SelectedCity
          select new Classes.MedicalCityRegionView();


  listView_MainContent.DataSource = result.ToList();
  listView_MainContent.DataBind();
```

And the error I get;

```
An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in 
System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: DataBinding: 
'MedicalBootStrap.Classes.MedicalCityRegionView' does not 
contain a property with the name 'MedicalID'.
```

Since Medical Entity does contain MedicalID, I thought "public Entity.Medical V_Medical { get; set; }" would suffice.

And as you see on the image, there has been created 14records which is correct but they are null;

[image]

Could you please enlighten me about the issue?

Comment: @zimdanen aha, ok I am trying it, thanks

Comment: You need to bind your view to `V_Medical.MedicalID` and not just `MedicalID`

Comment: Please note that your Linq queries are just queries until you enumerate them by calling `ToList()` for example. Only then are they executed towards the data store. This means that you can build the base part of your query in one place and then apply the filters as you go. This will reduce duplication.

Comment: I mny be missing something, but you _select_ twice `select new MedicalCityRegionView();` meaning you return a new, empty class for every found row. I would fill the data from what i have been querying...

Comment: @MikaelÖstberg thanks for the tip, I will transform the code into that way but I couldnt understand the part binding V_Medical.MedicalID and not just MedicalID, where should I bind it exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure cause I haven't seen the code, but I suspect you have a failing data binding in the "aspx". Somewhere in the ListView that is. Remember that you have a list of `MedicalCityRegionView` objects. You have to use the properties on that view model in order to get to the actual entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing the screenshot confirms my suspicion...

try

```
IQueryable<MedicalCityRegionView> result = from mID in MCR_View.Medicals
                 join cs in MCR_View.Cities on mID.CityFK equals cs.CityID
                 join reg in MCR_View.Regions on cs.RegionFK equals reg.RegionID

                 select new MedicalCityRegionView()
                   { V_Medical = mID,
                     V_City = cs,
                     V_Region = reg };
```

and

```
result = from mID in em.Medicals
      join ms in em.MedicalServices on mID.MsMedicalFK 
      equals ms.ServiceID
      join c in em.Cities on mID.CityFK equals c.CityID
      join reg in em.Regions on c.RegionFK equals 
      reg.RegionID

      where ms.ServiceID == SelectedMedicalService 
      &&
      c.CityID == SelectedCity
      select new Classes.MedicalCityRegionView()
                  { V_Medical = mID,
                    V_City = c,
                    V_Region = reg,
                    V_MedicalService = ms};
```

That should give you data in your 14 instances.

For the rest, Medical.ID or Medical.MedicalID is reachable as MedicalCityRegionView.Medical.Id, and not directly on MedicalCityRegionView.

Comment: Now the code looks exactly like you suggested but I couldnt get the last part, I guess you also mean there is missing mapping between the Medical Entity and MedicalCityRegionView ViewModel right?

Comment: somewhere it seems you are retrieving MedicalCityRegionView.MedicalID, which does not exist. Find where it happens, and change it to MedicalCityRegionView.V_Medical.MedicalId or MedicalCityRegionView.V_Medical.ID, whichever property actually exists :)

Comment: ok now I got what you mean, on the asp side listview datakeynames somehow doesnt recognize any of your suggestions above. I am trying to  find an appropriate key for it. var result brings the records perfectly but I don't know what to write to the datakeynames, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, i _guess_ somewhere in your `lvlMainContent` you are deciding how your data is bound. I _guess_ you will find in ther ethat you refer to `MedicalCityRegionView.MedicalID'. That does not exist. I suggested alternatives earlier, but since i do not know the rest of your data model, you might want to look at that yourself, or at least post it instead of making me guess more ;)

Comment: = ) ok, I will look at the rest by myself but now I gotta sleep, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I far as I know, generating entities with just dummy get; set; approach is not enough to retrieve the data corresponding to database data. I think you can fix this issue out by mapping at least necessary fields in the definition of the entities.

I hope  this will work, good luck!

Comment: I thought, it would be taken care of automatically since I give the entities as the type of those functions, how and where should I do those mappings then?

Comment: I dont think that it is taken care of automatically because you are getting the results but they have all necessary fields with null value, right? That's why I thought the field mapping is missing.